# understading java stream from db query

Tags: java, stream

I took pluralsight lesson on java streams but still cant understand them I wanted to as for help on understanding them. If for example I have a method the returns a query from the db.

`Mapper.selectById(id)`

and I want to create a stream and get all the columns names into a list which i would use

`Mapper.selectById(id).filter().collect()` but I cant picture out how it does the getting of all comes that is names only and how to implement it as well or check if a name `John` is in result set i know i can use `Mapper.selectById(id).noneMatch` for this but i dont know how to implement

Can some please help explain in leyman terms on how streams really work that I can picture out

Comment: what api / library is `Mapper.selectById` and what does it return? The example doesn't look complete enough to know what you could do to get to columns for example. There are many explanations for the internals of streams but it's hard to tell what level of detail you would actually need to know (https://theboreddev.com/understanding-java-streams/ is probably way too much for example)

Comment: @zapl its an example method that return query result from db..i just wanted to know how to do those transactions with streams i cant picture them out how they work so i am asking for help here

Comment: The issue for me is that it's really unclear what kind of Stream you have, what properties there are to work with, what you mean by "transactions" in this context and what you actually want to do. Would it be something like `boolean hasJohn = Mapper.selectById(id).anyMatch(row -> row.name().equals("John"))` ? Can you explain with details what your input (stream) looks like and what the desired output would be? What class is `Mapper`, is that part of some framework? can you show some example code of what you're doing and trying to solve?